# Ubuntu entry in Windows Vista still there, even after uninstall

Tags: installation, dual-boot, wubi, windows-vista

OK, so the other day I had a disc that I had burned Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala to. So I though, "Hey! Why not dual boot my computer?" I inserted the disc into drive `E`, ran Wubi, installed it, and rebooted.

However, when Windows shut down and my computer restarted, the BIOS boot screen never came up for about 10 minutes. In a panic, I did a hard shutdown on my computer (which was a bad move, by the way) and afterwards, I turned my computer back on and it booted Windows fine, but it said **wubildr.mbr** was missing or corrupt.

When I reinstalled Wubi, there were TWO Ubuntu entries and both continued the installation process. But When I uninstalled Wubi, I still had a renegade Ubuntu entry saying **wubildr.mbr** was missing or corrupt. Any ideas on how to get rid of that entry?

Thanks in advance =]

Answer (score 2):

In windows:
My computer -> properties -> Advanced -> Startup and Recovery settings.

Other option is to edit C:\boot.ini with a text editor and remove the line referencing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1), then open it. CLick on "Edit Boot Menu" and delete the "Ubuntu" entry.